# Visual Studio Debugging: Why does a variable show up in "Locals" but not "Watch"?

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, watch

I am debugging C code in Visual Studio (Version 12.0.31101.00).  I see a parameter "operatorArray_in" show up in the "Locals" because, well, it is local to where the breakpoint is.  Makes sense.

But when I open the "Watch" window and type in "operatorArray_in,9" or even "operatorArray_in", I get the error message 'identifier "operatorArray_in" is undefined'.

Why am I able to watch the variable in one window but not the other?  I can watch local variables in C#...

Comment: I have the same problem and can't find out why

Comment: It could be that the variable is not properly qualified with it's scope/namespace/parent class, etc. If you right-click on the variable in the text editor and choose Add Watch then Visual Studio may properly qualify it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turn off code optimalization? It helped to me.